# AWS - Error: local-exec provisioner error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am a newbie to terraform and I am trying to access the packages in the S3 bucket but getting “Error: local-exec provisioner error”. lamda-deploy python script used in the below code (tf module) is used to access the packages in the AWS S3 bucket. Kindly help me to understand how to resolve this issue.

Error:

```
Error: local-exec provisioner error

│ with module.serverless_projects[“api/contentful.zip”].null_resource.serverless_deployment,
│ on serverless_project/deployment.tf line 6, in resource “null_resource” “serverless_deployment”:
│ 6: provisioner “local-exec” {
│ Error running command ‘lambda-deploy api/contentful.zip’: exit status 1.

    Code:
    ======
    resource “null_resource” “serverless_deployment” {
    triggers = {
    source_version = data.aws_s3_object.package_object.version_id
    }

    provisioner “local-exec” {
    command = “lambda-deploy ${var.package_name}”*
    }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you do it this way, using a null provisioner to tell something outside of Terraform to publish the Lambda function, instead of using the Terraform `aws_lambda_function` resource? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function

Comment: @MarkB, Thanks for your response. Since I am new to terraform and also I am working on the existing tf/python modules which was build an year ago. serverless_deployment has all the package list and lamda-deploy will process these packages one by one. Now I would like to know how to get rid of this error without any wholesale changes to it. 

I could see the packages available in the S3 bucket path but still getting local-exec provision error. Is this issue related to the tf module which is shown above or the lambda-deploy python script which S3 bucket packages. Kindly help me on this query.